# How to get the time from one moment and append in other

Tags: javascript, momentjs

How to set the time in below case -

In Moment js,  The way I am setting the day `.day(day)`, I wanted to update time from my `futureDate` to `today` date,
How I can achieve that in moment.

I am taking the time from this `timeOnly`

```
timeOnly = moment(futureDate).format("hh:mm:ss")
```

In result,
now I am taking day and time from `futureDate` and updating here but format is not working.

```
result = moment(today)
            .format(timeOnly)
            .day(day)
            .format("x");
```

Full code below -

```
let result, timeValue, today, futureDate, timeOnly;
const { time, day } = this.state;

timeValue = new Date(time);
futureDate = moment(timeValue, "HH:mm")
    .day(day)
    .toDate();

timeOnly = moment(futureDate).format("hh:mm:ss")
today = new Date();

if (moment(futureDate) > moment(today)) {
    result = moment(today)
        .format(timeOnly)
        .day(day)
        .format("x");
}
```

DO I have to get the one by one and then set ? like below I did for hours etc.

```
moment().hour();
```

I am trying to do this. please suggest.

```
_calculateDate = () => {
        let result, timeValue, today, futureDate, hourOnly, minOnly, secOnly;
        const { time, day } = this.state;

        timeValue = new Date(time);
        futureDate = moment(timeValue, "HH:mm")
            .day(day)
            .toDate();

        hourOnly = moment(futureDate).hour();
        minOnly = moment(futureDate).minute();
        secOnly = moment(futureDate).second();
        today = new Date();

        if (moment(futureDate) > moment(today)) {
            result = moment(today)
                .hour(hourOnly)
                .minute(minOnly)
                .second(secOnly)
                .day(day)
                .format("x");
        } else {
            result = moment(today)
                .add(1, "weeks")
                .day(day)
                .hour(hourOnly)
                .minute(minOnly)
                .second(secOnly)
                .format("x");
        }
        return result;
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

This is want I did, for getting and then setting the value.

```
_calculateDate = () => {
        let result, timeValue, today, futureDate, hourOnly, minOnly, secOnly;
        const { time, day } = this.state;

        timeValue = new Date(time);
        futureDate = moment(timeValue, "HH:mm")
            .day(day)
            .toDate();

        hourOnly = moment(futureDate).hour();
        minOnly = moment(futureDate).minute();
        secOnly = moment(futureDate).second();
        today = new Date();

        if (moment(futureDate) > moment(today)) {
            result = moment(today)
                .hour(hourOnly)
                .minute(minOnly)
                .second(secOnly)
                .day(day)
                .format("x");
        } else {
            result = moment(today)
                .add(1, "weeks")
                .day(day)
                .hour(hourOnly)
                .minute(minOnly)
                .second(secOnly)
                .format("x");
        }
        return result;
    };
```